# making multiple ajax calls to send and receive data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am not sure if this is even possible

I have a series of divs, each divs with unique ID. I want to retrieve information in ref to those IDs through ajax. I can get all those ids push it into an array and then send it through ajax once. I get that and have done that and works fine. But now I am trying to make separate ajax calls for each of those divs and draw data back for each of those cells. So basically the if there are four divs there will be four separate calls. here is what I have so far which basically going to the last and stopping.

```
<div class = "pCell firstCell">
    <span id="26551826" class="cross"/>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
<div class = "pCell">
    <span id="22956811" class="cross"/>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
<div class = "pCell lastCell">
    <span id="22959266" class="cross"/>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

and the jquery looks like this

```
$(".pCell").each(function(index) {
        var pids = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "${URLUtils.url('http://someUrl')}",
        data: { PidVals: pids}
        }).done(function(data) {
        $(this).html(data);

       });

    });
```

Could this be even done?

Comment: `$(this)` in your `.done` doesn't refer to the active element in the `.each` iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `this` changes once you're in the `ajax` context.
You should do the following:

```
$(".pCell").each(function(index, element) {
    var pids = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "${URLUtils.url('http://someUrl')}",
    data: { PidVals: pids}
    }).done(function(data) {
    $(element).html(data);

   });

});
```

jQuery's `.each` takes two parameters, the second one is the current element in the matching set.

Comment: Nice... :) it's useful to remember, that each method's "this" doesn't necessarily point to the same thing. In other cases you can create a variable and set it as "=this" to be able to access it in inner functions.

Comment: I think create a variable and set it as "=this" is smart. Just did that. works great. Thanks again